# webapp2: How to find session by custom session id?

Tags: google-app-engine, safari, webapp2, facebook-canvas

How to find session by custom session id on webapp2? I can't use cookie in facebook canvas in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the session management module that is builtin with webapp2. You can find the docs for its session management here: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html